# Excel is not recognizing semicolons

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the covariance of these values (its 500 in total but ill give a few)

```
023399319;0
002512513;0
002896662;-0

COVAR(C2:C499)
```

it gives me N/A and it says "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments." How can I make the semicolon recognized?

Comment: Maybe text-to-columns to make your arrays two different columns? I don't think covar works with just one column.

Comment: how do i do that? thanks!

Comment: Highlight you column, then go do Data... Text-to-Columns. Choose delimited by semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the COVAR function, it compares two values or two arrays. In your example, you are trying to compare these 500 values. You can split them up using text functions using the following steps.

1. `=LEFT(C2,FIND(";",C2)-1)` - Fill all the way down. This will get you your first array.
2. `=RIGHT(C2, LEN(C2) - FIND(";",C2))` - Fill this all the way down. This will get you your second array.

Finally, you can then do `=COVAR(D2:499,E2:499)`

Comment: Misunderstood the question originally. This should get you the correct answer.